# Asymptotic behavior of $1/(a^2+\epsilon^2)$ as $\epsilon\to0$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

A limit that often arises in physics is
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{ \epsilon }{ a^2 + \epsilon^2 } = \pi \delta(a) ............ (1)
$$
Is there a similar sort of limit for
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{ 1 }{ a^2 + \epsilon^2 } = \frac{1}{a^2} + ???
$$
For $a \neq 0$, this limit is well-defined and can easily be computed. For $a = 0$, it blows. Can this blow-up be described in terms of any delta function as in (1) of derivatives thereof?

Comment: Can someone please explain what is unclear in this question? To me it seems perfectly clear, but if it is not, I will gladly modify it.

Comment: What is $\pi\delta(a)$?

Comment: No, the second limit is just $a^{-2}$. For the first function we have $\int \frac{\epsilon da}{a^2+\epsilon^2} = \arctan\left(\frac{a}{\epsilon}\right)$ and the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ is finite for all $a$ (and independent of $a$ for all $a\not=0$). For the second function this is not the case.

Comment: @Winther - I see. I also realized that. We can write $\frac{1}{a^2 + \epsilon^2 } - \frac{1}{a^2} = -\frac{1}{a^2} \frac{\epsilon^2}{a^2+ \epsilon^2}$. The limit of this is then clearly zero.

Comment: @nullUser - $\pi$ is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter in flat space and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac Delta function (or rather, distribution).